# Split a csv based on values in a column then merge/bind the output by row

Tags: r, split, rbind

I have a csv file containing 4 columns (YY,MM,DD,RR). Here's the sample data:

[Link to data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9faET7Bc2o8aXB4cFl3ekZoTFk/view?usp=sharing)

The current format has 9861 rows and 4 colums like this (daily data from 1981-2007):

```
YY,MM,DD,RR
1981,1,1,0
1981,1,2,0
1981,1,3,-9999
1981,1,4,-9999
1981,1,5,0
1981,1,6,0
.....
.....
2007,1,31,-9999
```

I want split the csv file per year. The output should be 27 csv files with the same number of columns.
For example, 1981.csv contains:

```
YY, MM, DD, RR
1981, 1, 1, 0.4
1981, 1, 2, 0
.....
.....
1981, 12, 31, 0.5
```

Here's my script:

```
dat <- read.csv("test_dat.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
spt1<-split(dat,dat$YY)
lapply(names(spt1), function(x){write.csv(spt1[[x]], file = paste0("output",x, sep = "",".csv"),row.names=F)})
```

I want to bind the output csv files by row such that the output will look like this:

```
 YY,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,......,365
1981,val1,val2,.............,val365
...
...
2008,val1,val2,.............,val365
```

Leap years should have 366 days.

Is there an easy to do this in R?

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Given you've got a date in three columns and some kind of measurement, spreading to wide form is really ill-advised. Further, it's unclear how you're trying to reshape, as you don't have an ID variable to turn into headers.

Comment: @alistaire. I tried to create a dummy column like this: dat$test<-seq(1,9861,1) so that I can use it as headers but when I tried the dcast, the values are all NAs. The MM and DD is not yet important.

Comment: Well right, `RR` only has one value per row, so your columns will only have one non-`NA` value per column in wide form. Thus why this is not a useful transformation; 9681 * 4 != 27 * 9862.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataframe like this, you can run a loop

```
YY <- seq(1981, 2007,1)     #Defining years
RR <- runif(27,0,30)        #Defining another random column, replace this with your respective columns

df <- data.frame(YY,RR)     #created data frame
df$YY <- as.factor(df$YY)   #ignore this step if your year column is already a factor

for (i in levels(df$YY)) {      #run a for loop for each year
  year <- i
  df.subset <- df[df$YY %in% year,]     #subset your data as per year
  write.csv(df.subset,file = paste(year,"csv",sep = "."))   #save the subset df in a new file with year as file name
}
```

Comment: @Hardik.Many thanks for the reply. I think your solution is more elegant than mine. After splitting the files, is there a way to concatenate them by row?I edited my question above. Is it possible to add a "bind" command inside the loop of your script?

Comment: Initially i was just planning to transform the csv file but based from the comments of @alistaire, this kind of transformation is not ok. So I decided to split them first then bind again as a workaround solution. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Hey how are you getting the val1, val2 values? your initial df had only 4 columns including the year

Comment: I just assigned them as an example. Not the output of the script. They should be actual values. The values are from the RR column.

Comment: the column of your interest in RR along with year?

Comment: yes. Your code is already working. I just wanted to bind the outputs to one data frame.